# Subscription class not found 'MyChannel' in ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncable

I am facing a problem while working with Action Cable, whenever I run my program I receive an error that says `Subscription` Class not found `ConversationChannel`

and when I try to send a message I get this log

> Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET,
>   HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) Subscription class
>   not found: "ConversationChannel" Could not execute command from
>   {"command"=>"message",
>   "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"ConversationChannel\"}",
>   "data"=>"{\"message\":[{\"name\":\"conversation_id\",\"value\":\"2\"},{\"name\":\"amitian_id\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"name\":\"body\",\"value\":\"nmm\"}],\"action\":\"speak\"}"})
>   [RuntimeError - Unable to find subscription with identifier:
>   {"channel":"ConversationChannel"}]:
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.1/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:74:in
>   `find' |
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.1/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:53:in`
>   perform_action' |
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.1/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:17:in
>   `execute_command' |
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.1/lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb:88:in`dispatch_websocket_message' |
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.1/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:58:in
>   `block in invoke'

`ConversationChannel.rb`

```
class ConversationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # stream_from "some_channel"
    stream_from "conversations-#{current_amitian.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end

  def speak(data)

    message_params = data['message'].each_with_object({}) do |el, hash|
      hash[el.values.first] = el.values.last
    end

    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "conversations-#{current_amitian.id}",
      message: message_params
    )
  end 
 end
```

`conversation.js`

```
App.conversation = App.cable.subscriptions.create("ConversationChannel", {
  connected: function() {

  },
  disconnected: function() {

  },
  received: function(data) {
  console.log(data['message']);
  },
  speak: function(message) {
    return this.perform('speak' , {
    message: message
    });
  }
});

$(document).on('submit', '.new_message', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var values = $(this).serializeArray();
  App.conversation.speak(values);
  $(this).trigger('reset');
});
```

connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_amitian

    def connect
        self.current_amitian = find_verified_amitian
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_amitian
        if(current_amitian = env['warden'].amitian)
            current_amitian
        else
            reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
    end
  end
end
```

using the log file given above can anyone tell me why It can't find my `conversation_channel.rb` file ?

Answer (score 27):

I have resolved it by moving the channel file up one directory.

From `app/channels/application_cable/conversation_channel.rb` 
to `app/channels/conversation_channel.rb`

Answer (score 8):

You have to provide the full Module::Class name in your client (JS) code. For e.g. if your `ConversationChannel` class is inside `ApplicationCable` module then in your client instead of just `ConversationChannel` you need to do `ApplicationCable::ConversationChannel`

Comment: I found that I needed to include the Channel class as well: `ApplicationCable::Channel::CountsChannel`

Answer (score 1):

Your file needs to named as `conversation_channel.rb`, as snake_case is the rails convention for channel file names.

Comment: In your post you mentioned that your file name is `ConversationChannel.rb`. Is that not the case? Check for any typos in the file name?